# translating C++ snippet

Tags: c++

I am working on porting a framework from C++ to Java, and it is turning out to be harder than I expected, as I don't know a whole lot about C++. I came across this one snippet that I don't really understand. If someone could tell me what the lines marked do that would be awesome.

```
  /** Heap data, stored as a vector */
  std::vector< std::pair< _Tp, _Val > > data;

  /** Maps objects to their positions in the data vector */
  std::map< _Tp, int> mapping;


  //I understand that this method takes a pair of type <_Tp, _Val>
  template <class _Tp, class _Val>
  void Heap<_Tp,_Val>::push(std::pair< _Tp, _Val > x)
  {
    int index=data.size();

    //Here is where I run into trouble
    //I can't seem to figure out what this line is doing
    //I know it is inserting a Key-Value pair into the map
    //but why is .second being called? and what exactly is this if statement
    //checking?
    if (mapping.insert(std::make_pair(x.first,index)).second)
    {
      data.push_back(x);
      percolate_up(index);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The `insert` member function returns a pair whose `bool` component returns true if an insertion was made and false if the map already contained an element whose key had an equivalent value in the ordering, and whose iterator component returns the address where a new element was inserted or where the element was already located.

So that code is adding an element to the `map`, and if the element wasn't already there it pushes the data into the `vector`.

Comment: oh ok, thank you. The page I was looking at didnt list a pair return value..lame. I'll have to be more careful with sites I take information from. thanks

Comment: @Hunter - returning a pair is not the "Standard" behaviour.  I imagine you are using VC++?!  Relying on the return of the pair for a vector insert is non-portable.  So the page you were looking at may not have been wrong, it just doesn't match your compiler.

Comment: @Michael: Is not a vector insert but a map insert, and the pair return is there in the C++11 standard, is this not valid in C++03?

Comment: @K-ballo - sorry, meant map.  I'm not a language lawyer, but I don't think that C++03 standard defines the return of a pair.  I have had issues with this in the past going from VC++ on Win to gcc on *nix.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/) for an example of a void return.

Answer (score 3):

The `insert` member function used here returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, where the `bool` member is `true` if an insertion was made. So, the `if` statement is seeing if the `insert` call actually added a record to the map.

You might find it useful to refer to the documentation of the standard library when working with C++ - [here's the MSDN page on map::insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ac0zkz%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your comment, I didnt see that return type listed on the page I was looking at. Also, thank you for the link